# How to add a dependent project to an android gradle project that builds a debug or release jar approprately

Tags: android, build, dependencies, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need a clear example of how to extend an Android Gradle project with an arbitrary project.

By arbitrary I mean that it can't just use the 'java' plugin since it doesn't support buildTypes to my knowledge. I am currently using an 'ant' task for this, which has two targets for debug and release, however I don't see how to tie it into an Android project.

Assume that your dependent project must build pure Java source in two ways:

1. debug build that produces a debug version in 'purejava.jar'
2. release build that produces a release version in 'purejava.jar'
   The jar 'purejava.jar' is to be placed such that the Android project (could be a multi-project) is able to reference it at compile time, and it must therefore be the correct build to support both the debug and release configurations of the Android project.

How should this be tackled?

Since I am new to Android Studio and Gradle, I don't have a clear idea of how to manipulate extensions generated by the Android plugin, which are not available until after project evaluation.

How should the Android project be made dependent on this pure java project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer, with following project structure:

```
MyProject
    -- MyAndroidLib
        -- JarProject
```

This represents the gradle top project 'MyProject' which has a sub-project 'MyAndroidLib' which is dependent on a pure java project 'JarProject' which is built with different code for debug than for release builds.

I'll take advantage of Android's 'debugCompile' and 
'releaseCompile' configurations. In the Android sub-project ('MyAndroidLib') that is dependent on the jars, add following lines to the dependencies:

```
//MyAndroidLib build.gradle
def jarProject = project(':MyProject:MyAndroidLib:JarProject')
def jarPath = pcfProject.projectDir.toString()
dependencies {
    ....
    compile jarProject
    debugCompile files(jarPath + '/' + jarProject.debugJarName)
    releaseCompile files(jarPath + '/' + jarProject.releaseJarName)
}
```

The 'jarProject' def is defined to simplify accessing it from the MyAndroidLib project. (If you know a better way ...)

The main point of this is to define a separate debug and release jar path for the 'debugCompile' and 'releaseCompile' configurations. The 'debugJarName' and 'releaseJarName' are defined in a gradle.properties file for the JarProject as follows:

```
//JarProject gradle.properties
debugJarName=jarproject_d.jar
releaseJarName=jarproject_r.jar
```

In the gradle file for JarProject define a task that builds BOTH jar files named by this properties file. In my case, they are built right in the project folder by the 'compile' target of an ant build file located in that project.

```
//JarProject build.gradle
apply plugin: 'java'

project.ext.set("debugJar", file(projectDir.toString() + "/" + debugJarName))
project.ext.set("releaseJar",file(projectDir.toString() + "/" + releaseJarName))

task buildJars(type: Exec)  {
    description 'Build the debug and release jars for the JarProject'
    outputs.files debugJar,releaseJar
    commandLine 'ant', 'compile'
}

task compileJava.dependsOn('buildJars')

artifacts {
    buildJars
}

clean.dependsOn('cleanBuildJars')

clean << {
    exec {
        commandLine 'ant', 'clean'
    }
}
```

I took advantage of the 'java' plugin since it defines a 'compile' interface, and I haven't figured out how to build this from scratch, or even from the 'base' plugin. This project takes advantage of the automatic 'cleanBuildJars' task created because I defined the outputs in 'buildJars' task. This is necessary in order to have them built as needed. I probably need to define the 'inputs' too, since if they change ...

If anyone sees how my first stumblings in the gradle/Android world can be improved, pls. add comments as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If it weren't for the fact that you need debug and release versions of your library, then your Android app could depend on a plain Java module just fine -- you could set up the library with the `java` plugin and put a `compile project` statement in the app's `dependencies` and it would work fine.

However, the Java plugin is never going to understand Android's notion of build types (unless GradleWare adds it at some point), so you can't propagate that to your Java modules. You could set up your plain Java project as an Android library and use the `android-library` plugin (you'll have to dummy out the manifest and other Android-specific stuff it expects to see in Android libraries), but you'll run into a different problem: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962 is a bug that reports that the build type is not propagated to library modules.

Until that bug is fixed, or if you're unwilling to make your plain Java library an android library, I think your only approach is to make two different versions of your library, compile them to different jar files, and selectively pull in dependencies.

Comment: Yes, what I'm trying to get at is HOW does one do this? (selectively pull the different jar files according to the Android build type).

Comment: That's a good question. On further thought, the solution isn't obvious to me. Not to say it's impossible, but it's beyond my Gradle knowledge.

Comment: In Android doc at: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Android-tasks there is a section "Dependencies on binary packages" where they mention they have a 'debugCompile' and a 'releaseCompile' configuration. If follows one could modify the dependencies of the android project dependent on a release or debug jar accordingly:in the dependencies section add "debugCompile files ('libs/pure_d.jar')" and similar for 'releaseCompile'. This does not work at present, probably due to the bug you mentioned above.